# NEO4J Query and Data Output very slow

Tags: database, performance, neo4j, cypher

I have a hardware Server (2x 6 CPU Intel e5, 128GB DDR3 RAM, NVM-SSDs)
Config in .config-files for RAM are:

- dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=25g
- dbms.memory.heap.max_size=25g
- dbms.memory.pagecache.size=40g
- dbms.memory.transaction.global_max_size=20g

I have a tree structure. For test purpose I genereated a Tree where each parent has 15 children with a depth of 4. (depth: 0=>15, 1=> 225, 2=>3.375, 3=>50k 4=>760k)

If I want to output a lot of nodes the query gets stuck.

Nodes are persons with a only a few attributes:
-id (from neo4j)
-status
-customerid
-level (depth of tree)

The Nodes are linked in two ways:
:UPLINE from deeper level pointing at root
:DOWNLINE from root to leaves

My Query for getting the tree:

**MATCH p = (r:Person {VM:1})-[:DOWNLINE *]->(x)

RETURN DISTINCT nodes(p) AS Customer

LIMIT 5000**

Started streaming 5000 records after 2 ms and completed after 42 ms, displaying first 1000 rows.

Displaying the data takes so long even for 5000 records. It takes like 30s to display the nodes or show them in a table.

For a test I created a tree structure in a **MySQL and SQL-Server database** with the schema:

ID--------ManagerID-------Status
1 -----------  [-]  ----------- active
2 ------------  1  ----------- active
...
15 -----------  1  ----------- active
16 -----------  2  ----------- inactive
17 -----------  2  ----------- active
...

If I query that with CTE (recursive) I get faster times then on NEO4j.

Am I wrong thinking that NEO4j should be faster at this task?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you considered using MySQL rather than Neo4j for your project?

Comment: Try profiling your query once to see, what the query planner is doing, like this:
`PROFILE MATCH p = (r:Person {VM:1})-[:DOWNLINE *]->(x)
RETURN DISTINCT nodes(p) AS Customer
LIMIT 5000` and then try this query to see if it performs the same work optimally or not:
`MATCH (r:Person {VM:1})-[:DOWNLINE]->(x)
RETURN DISTINCT r AS Customer
LIMIT 5000`

Comment: Here is the Profile Match: https://pasteboard.co/NKZwA8A4TI08.png

Comment: This profile graph is for the query `MATCH p = (r:Person {VM:1})-[:DOWNLINE *]->(x)
RETURN DISTINCT nodes(p) AS Customer
LIMIT 5000`,  I believe, how much time does it took to execute the profile query

Comment: What's the size of the result data? The overall time (30 seconds, as you said) represents a mix of: database evaluating the query, determining results, etc. as well as separately shipping data to your computer for viewing. If the result data for 5000 records is large enough, and/or network throughput to your computer is slow enough, it could take a while.

Comment: It was executed on the server itself. The dataset was not that big. 3 data columns * 5000 = 15.000 single entries is not much data, considering that there is only a single value as an entry.